# VLC 3.0 not working with input-repeat=-1

Tags: vlc, libvlc

This is my first post, not sure this is the correct place for it, if not please let me know.

I have C++ code running using VLCLib (from 0.x to 2.2.8) which works the way I intended.

Background info: I simply do a `loadlibrary` on libvlc.dll and then do a `GetProcAddress` on the entry points. (This works fine on both 2.2.x and 3.0)

Here is my new issue/question.
Using 2.2.8 I can play a file and it loops infinitely as requested, running the exact same code with VLC 3.0 plays the file only once, and does not loop/repeat.

```
// This is the line of code responsible for the looping.

pfnlibvlc_media_add_option(m_pVLCMedia, "input-repeat=-1");
```

In VLC 3.0 I set the `libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached` event, but it never hits, I tried other events as sanity checks such as `libvlc_MediaPlayerPlaying` and this triggered.

Does anyone know if VLC 3.0 functionality has changed? I searched both the VLC wiki and StackOverflow and I can't find anything on this.

Thanks for the advice,
Marc

Comment: Not sure what happened, I have been running more tests to understand: the statement about libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached not being reached is false, what I do get at the end of the video file is a libvlc_MediaPlayerStopped

Answer (score 2):

So, for the VLC >3.0 you can't add the negative value of `"input-repeat"` to the parameter. Your string must look like `input-repeat=65545` References to the issue - https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/96